# LAS Point Statistics as Raster in ArcGIS Pro fails to write raster

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-pro, las, error-000210, arcgis-10.7

In the past I was able to use the ArcGIS tool `LAS Point Statistics as Raster`, but it is failing to work in ArcGIS Pro 2.2 or ArcGIS 10.7 on Windows 10.

After creating an LAS dataset, issuing the following command results in an error message:

```
arcpy.management.LasPointStatsAsRaster('lasdataset', 'outraster', "POINT_COUNT", "CELL_SIZE", 10)
```

The ArcGIS error message is [000210](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/tool-errors-and-warnings/001001-010000/tool-errors-and-warnings-00201-00225-000210.htm), "Cannot create output". I have tried to write to both a geodatabase and a folder.

When I use the following command, the function works:

```
arcpy.management.LasPointStatsAsRaster('lasdataset', 'outraster', "POINT_COUNT", "OBSERVATIONS", 10)
```

I have tried it in ArcGIS 10.7, Pro 2.2 both in the GUI and using arcpy. I really need a cell size of 10 m, and the observations cell size is huge.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that my LAS dataset was in a geographic coordinate system and not a projected coordinate system, so the function was unable to interpret a consistent cell size.